# Advanced filtering in Django ORM. Need a one query solution instead of recursion

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a question regarding advanced filtering in Django ORM.

MODEL:

```
class ClubAgentMember(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='club_agent_players')
    agent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='agent_club_players')
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='member_club_agents')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

[image]

Goal is like this:
For example I have initial `agent_id` = 15 and I need to find all agents id of agents that are connected to the initial agent. I know how to do it via recursion. On the small sample is fine but on a bigger sample it would slow down DB drastically. So that I need to pull all data in 1 query.
Resulting query set should be `[ 15, 19, 22]` – agent_id

How to read chart:
Initial agent has `id= 15` (yellow).  Members with `id [18, 19, 27, 28]` attached to this agent(orange). One of this members (*one only in this eample, might be 2 or more or all, depends*)is an agent himself, number `19` (green).
On a next level we have initial agent `19` (green) and he has members `[22, 31, 32]` attached to him. One of them is an agent himself 22 (red).
Next level agent `ID=22`, his members are `[37, 38, 39]` . None of them is an agent. So we done here.

At the end I need to have id of all connected agents(who are connected to the initial agent) in this sequence, that is `agent_id` `[15, 19, 22]` in our scenario.
Initaial agent id comes from `request.user.id` and it might be different

Raw SQL is also possible , if it is not possible to do via Django ORM
Django version I have 2.0.7

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't want a lot of SQL queries, your best bet could be to load all instances of this model into memory (a single query with `.objects.all()`) and then do the recursive searching in Python code without further queries.

Comment: @Ralf. On a sample with 30.000 enties for example, it would be over one second (overal API time), which is not good. I need to be inside one sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to query all data into memory and do the recursion inside Python. To reduce processing time the query can be reduced to the minimum data necessary with [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) (no ORM conversion to classes, just the raw values) and using Python `sets` can allow fast look-up.

The code could look similar to this:

```
import collections
agents = collections.defaultdict(set)
for agent_id, member_id in ClubAgentMember.objects.values_list('agent_id', 'member_id'):
    agents[agent_id].add(member_id)

start_agent_id = 15
agents_to_check = {start_agent_id, }
result_agent_set = set()

while len(agents_to_check) > 0:
    agent_id = agents_to_check.pop()
    result_agent_set.add(agent_id)

    for member_id in agents.get(agent_id, []):
        if member_id in agents:
            agents_to_check.add(member_id)

print('result_agent_set', result_agent_set)
```

In a comment you said

> On a sample with 30.000 enties for example, it would be over one second (overal API time), which is not good.

Is this code proposal still to slow for your use case, with your data?

Comment: thank you for ttaking part in this post. Your solution is definetelly a plan 'B' for me in case i didnt find SQL based solution. I just now looking into WINDOW functions as a possible way out.. Anyway, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
create materialized view  players_view as
(
WITH RECURSIVE players AS (
    SELECT agent_id,
           player_id
    FROM clubs_clubagentplayer
    WHERE agent_id = 15
    UNION
    SELECT sub.agent_id,
           sub.player_id
    FROM clubs_clubagentplayer as sub
             INNER JOIN players as main ON main.player_id = sub.agent_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT agent_id
FROM players
    )
```